# Embed excel into word using vba does not always display the top of the embedded sheet

Tags: excel, vba, embed, ms-word

I have a Word document with VBA code to embed multiple excel sheets using the following process i.e. addOLEObject

```
Set IllSheet = _
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("example1").Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", filename:=filename1, LinkToFile:=False)
```

however on occasion the embedded spreadsheet does not display at the top of the sheet but seemingly randomly scrolled part way down the sheet. I have checked and the excel sheet is saved with it scrolled to the top.

How can I ensure the sheet embedded is always scrolled to the top?

I can access the embedded sheet and input values as per below but can not seem to find a suitable line of code to ensure that the sheet displays at the top of active sheet.

```
Set objOLE = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(3).OLEFormat
    objOLE.Activate
    objOLE.Object.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = Format(Funds, "#,###0")
    Selection.MoveRight
    objOLE.Object.Application.Quit
    DoEvents
```

I have tried scroll functions etc and also want to avoid using SendKeys because it is so unreliable.

Any help greatly appreciated.

M

Comment: `objOLE.Object.ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Select`

Comment: Thanks for the reponse - however I get a run-time error 1004 -
Select method of Range class failed???

Comment: Hm, can you explicitly define the sheet name instead of `ActiveSheet`? I don't think that's really the issue since you use it to set the cell value. I'm not sure if this will work with an embed, but this should be a valid method of the cells object. Admittedly, I never use `.Select` so I could be on the wrong track.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same runtime - it is frustrating as you say - you can edit the value of the cell using .value however you can not select! It is hard to find guidance on what OLEFORMAT can actual do in excel - thanks again for the help - mr scruff